# Are there any rules to differ between Errors, Warnings and Notifications?

Tags: usability, error-message

I am looking for any rules to give developers how they can differ between `Errors`, `Warnings` and `Notifications`. I haven't found something in literature or the web.

Is there a standard that needs to be followed?

Comment: What is the context ? Web app, mobile ? type of application , audience ? This will help in providing a related answer.

Comment: Developers or designers?

Comment: how they can differ talking about design or definitions? what's the context?

Comment: For me, Errors, Warnings, and Notifications are the part of a user flow. Why do you want to delegate UX to developers?

Comment: Very contextual.
There are no hard rules in this field I think. :)
Why would they request this?

Comment: I try to answer the questions :)

Context is for a Style Guide for some industrial environment. Right now this is not in typical stand-alone PC-Stuff but could get mobile.  I want to give the SW-Developers decisions points, what they should use in specific cases since they have _no_ Usability Background.

Answer (score 1):

Syslog has 8 levels of logging. They are pretty good:

> **DEBUG**: Info useful to developers for debugging the app, not useful
>   during operations
>
> **INFORMATIONAL**: Normal operational messages - may be harvested for
>   reporting, measuring throughput, etc - no action required
>
> **NOTICE**: Events that are unusual but not error conditions - might be
>   summarized in an email to developers or admins to spot potential
>   problems - no immediate action required
>
> **WARNING**: Warning messages - not an error, but indication that an error
>   will occur if action is not taken, e.g. file system 85% full - each
>   item must be resolved within a given time
>
> **ERROR**: Non-urgent failures - these should be relayed to developers or
>   admins; each item must be resolved within a given time
>
> **ALERT**: Should be corrected immediately - notify staff who can fix the
>   problem - example is loss of backup ISP connection
>
> **CRITICAL**: Should be corrected immediately, but indicates failure in a
>   primary system - fix CRITICAL problems before ALERT - example is loss
>   of primary ISP connection
>
> **EMERGENCY**: A "panic" condition - notify all tech staff on call?
>   (earthquake? tornado?) - affects multiple apps/servers/sites...

From: http://www.kiwisyslog.com/help/syslog/index.html?protocol_levels.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Error:** blocks user's progress; a condition that must be addressed.

**Warning:** something doesn't look right, but the user can choose to continue.

**Notification:** information that is helpful or valuable for the user, but everything is in order.

Comment: I'd say: Error; program issue. Something's broken somehow.
Warning; program works fine but continuing this course of action may lead to bad results.

Comment: @PixelSnader isn't a sign in error an ... error?

Comment: hm yeah I hadn't thought about that.

Comment: @PixelSnader I've spent way too much of my life thinking about error and warning conditions 